# modal edit form wont display

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

using bootstrap 3.1 with mvc4.  I had the modal form displaying fine, but no data in the form.  Once I fixed the data populating the edit form (at least I know it hit the controller an received data), the screen is grayed but the form is not displayed.  I can see the mark up in the developer tool. So for some reason, something changed when it got data.

I have an index view with 2 partial views.

Index (the jquery gets the data for the modal form):

```
@Html.Partial("_foresterEditForm", Model)

@Html.Partial("_foresterGrid", Model)

@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".btn-edit-forester").on("click", function () {
        var foresterid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("EditForester", "Forester")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { id: foresterid },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#edit-modal').html(data).modal('show');
            }

        })
    });
</script>
}
```

The modal is opened by a link in the grid:

```
 @<a href="#edit-modal" class="btn btn-default btn-edit-forester" data-toggle="modal">edit</a>
```

...and the top of the modal, which is in the second partial:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="edit-modal-label">Edit Forester</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditForester", "Forester", null,
                                new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                                    UpdateTargetId = "forester-grid"
                                }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">

... form elements, then closing divs.
```

EDIT:  I believe the problem may be with how I am returning the data from the controller, so here is the controller method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult EditForester(int id)
    {
        ForesterViewModel vm = new ForesterViewModel();
        vm.Forester = repo.GetForester(id);
        return PartialView("_foresterEditForm", vm);
    }
```

Comment: What are the contents of `data` on a successful `GET`?

Comment: I don't know how to find that out.  However, I think the problem is with the way I am returning the data from MVC, so I have added the controller code above.

Comment: At a minimum you should be able to stick `alert(data);` as the first line after `success: function (data) {`. It's crude, but should show the contents.

Comment: Cool.  I did that and it popped up a box with all the mark up for the modal form, with the values returned from the db.

Comment: Can you try replacing this line `$('#edit-modal').html(data).modal('show');` with `$('#edit-modal').modal('show');`. It would be nice to prove whether or not the markup in `data` is somehow screwing up the modal.

Comment: Ok I did that and the modal now displays fine, but with no values.

Comment: So inserting your markup into that `#edit-modal` div is definitely the cause of your problems. If the markup in `data` is correct, then likely you are inserting into the wrong location. What div is it supposed to be going in? I would normally guess `#modal-body` but looks like you are already populating that by other means.

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track.  It seems like I am returning the partial view which is entire modal, plus jquery is doing a "show" for the entire modal, so they are hitting each other.  I have to figure out how to splice them.

Comment: Yes, please see my recent answer as one simple approach. Please mark the answer as accepted if this process helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the sleuthing progress we've made so far, can you try the following:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="edit-modal-label">Edit Forester</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="test-modal-body-upper"></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditForester", "Forester", null,
                                new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                                    UpdateTargetId = "forester-grid"
                                }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">

... form elements, then closing divs.
```

and change the `GET` success function to:

```
success: function (data) {
                $('#test-modal-body-upper').html(data);
                $('#edit-modal').modal('show');
            }
```

This should display the two content blocks sequentially and prove that your overall concept is working. You could also try putting `class="modal-body"` attribute in the new div I added if it looks different than the rest of the modal. Hard to know the exact effects without seeing the CSS. If you literally need the two content blocks displayed on top of each other, you will need to consider transparency or special div markups.